# Возможно ли в Python посмотреть код библиотеки?

Tags: python

Существует ли способ просмотреть код в библиотеке Пайтона? Например BeautifulSoup хочу посмотреть как реализованы методы find, find_all, но не найду(( использую pycharm как среду. Библиотека установлена, а как код посмотреть её методов не знаю((

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нажмите на клавиатуре клавишу Ctrl и подведите курсор мыши к интересующему вас методу. Вы увидите, что метод стал ссылкой. Можете щелкнуть по ней и перейти к коду.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Namerek он использует.

Comment: @Namerek "использую pycharm как среду" написано же, э? А вообще в VSCode это тоже работает, насколько я помню.

Comment: @Namerek в вопросе об этом прямо написано

Comment: В PyCharm без мышки это делается через Ctrl+B. М меню Navigate есть ещё другие хоткеи для других переходов, например Ctrl+U - переход на суперметод.

Comment: @Эникейщик, старею ))) Пора очки покупать. Звиняйте )